# If M is an oriented topological n-Manifold, is M - {x} oriented?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Does removing a point from an oriented topological manifold result in a non-oriented manifold?

I know that if M - {x} is oriented, then M is oriented because we can use the two fold cover given in 3.3 of Hatcher. However, I am not able to see converse is true.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: quote form [The Manifold Atlas Project](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Orientation_of_manifolds#Orientation_of_topological_manifolds):

> An open subset of an oriented topological manifold is oriented by restring the charts in the maximal oriented atlas to the intersection with the open subset.

Answer (score 3):

No: you have this the wrong way round: removing a point from an orientable manifold can't make it unorientable (essentially because $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ are both orientable allowing you to convert an oriented atlas for $M$ into an oriented atlas for $M\setminus \{x\}$).

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "atlas". The way Hatcher defines orientations is a map sending each $x \in M \to \mu_x$, a local orientation.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology) for the definition of an atlas. With Hatcher's definition of orientability in terms of local orientations,  isn't it clear that a local orientation for $M$ restricts to a local orientation of $M \setminus \{x\}$?

Comment: Oh right, every orientation of M gives rise to an orientation of M - {x}...

Comment: The real projective plane without a point is the open Möbius strip, right?

Comment: @Turion: yes. thanks for the correction. I've removed the offending text.